# Custom precision bits in Pari C for t_REAL

Tags: c, precision, pari

I need custom precision bits for t_REAL in Pari C library.
I've tried changing the BITS_IN_LONG variable and made sure that I change that the precision exponent of my GEN variable, still I'm only getting a real number upto 39 decimal places.
Is there a function or some different GEN type that can store real numbers with greater precision?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a ***default*** called `realprecision` which you need to set.

In PARI/GP you use the function `default(realprecision, 1000)` to change the number of (decimal) significant digits for `t_REAL` to 1000 (or maybe a bit more). Here the magical name `realprecision` is the "key", and `1000` is the "value".

And when I check the manual for `default` it says:

> The library syntax is
>   `GEN default0(const char *key = NULL, const char *val = NULL)`.

So have you tried the function `default0`?

Comment: I tried changing the "realprecision" value, but it changed only by a factor of 32 bits (rounded). Moreover, it seemed to have a bound on the no. of significant bits.

Comment: @Deevashwer Did you change it to `1000` or what value? There should be no upper bound. I do not use the C library, but inside GP, when I do `default(realprecision, 1000)`, the value afterwards as seen with `default(realprecision)`, is `1001`. I use a 64-bit version. The help says: _Note  that PARI's internal precision works on a word basis  (by increments of 32 or 64 bits),  hence may be a little larger  than  the  number  of  decimal digits you expected._ Afterwards, when I do stuff like `exp(1.0)`, I get ~1000 figures.